# Transversality condition equation

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I'm somewhat baffled:
 I have a problem in  calculus of variations:

$$
\int_0^T \!(x-\dot x^2)dt,\qquad x(0)=0,\qquad x(T)=T^2-2.
$$

Let $
F(t,x, \dot x) =x-\dot x^2.
$

I calculate all the necessary derivatives:
$$F_x=1 \qquad F_{\dot x} = -2\dot x \qquad \frac{d}{dt}F_{\dot x} = -2\ddot x$$

and write down an Euler-Lagrange equation:
$1+2\ddot x=0$

And calculate my quotients:
$$x=c_1t+c_2-\frac{t^2}{4} \qquad x(0)=0 \Longrightarrow  c_2=0$$

And then I get stuck:
I know that if I have
$$
J = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} F(t,x,\dot x) dt
$$and the right end follows a curve $x=\varphi(t)$, the transversality condition should hold:
$$
F(t_2,x_2, \dot x_2) + [\dot \varphi(t_2)-\dot x_2]F_{\dot x}(t_2,x_2, \dot x_2) =0
$$
where $x_2=x(t_2)$.

But I can't wrap my mind about it: what is $\varphi$ in my case, and how would the transversality equation look like? 
Please help with any hints.

Comment: Thanks, Sharkos, for adding a tag.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use the condition $x(T) = T^2 -2$ to solve for $c_1$ and be done with it?

Comment: Well, I tried that. As you can see, I've found that $c_2=0$, so if I solve $x(T) = T^2 -2$ I'd have an equation about both $T$ and $c_1$, and I think I should only have an equation about one or the other.

Comment: I guess you can take $T$ as parameter and solve for boundary condition such as $x(T)=c_1T-\frac {T^2}4=T^2-2$

Comment: From the way the problem was presented, I assumed $T$ was a parameter. (Anil Baseski's point as well, I think.) I'd check the source of the problem to figure out whether $T$ is indeed a parameter. And even if it isn't, you could just solve the problem as if it is, then compute the target integral as a function of $T$, then optimize that function to choose $T$.

Comment: I do not understand your statement "...and the right end follows a curve x=\varphi(t)": I mean, $x=x(t)$ is already a curve $t\mapsto x(t)$ for all $t\in [t_1,t_2]$: why to introduce $\varphi$?. I think that the source of confusion here is about $t_2$: if we consider it as fixed, then the problem is solved, as already noticed by other members in the comments above. If $t_2$ is a variable, then your functional is of the form $J[x,t_2]=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} F(\tau,x(\tau),\dot{x}(\tau))d\tau$ and we are dealing with a different problem.